# Wine dataset LDA & PCA comparison - Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to run this [Comparison of LDA and PCA 2D projection of Iris dataset example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html)  with a WINE dataset that I download from the internet but I get the error:

```
d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:760: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().   y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-44-a42b504da984> in <module>
     14 
     15 for color, i, target_name in zip(colors, [0, 1, 2], target_names):
---> 16     plt.scatter(X_r[y == i, 0], X_r[y == i, 1], color=color, alpha=.8, lw=lw,
     17                 label=target_name)
     18 plt.legend(loc='best', shadow=False, scatterpoints=1)

IndexError: too many indices for array

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

How can I fix it?

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tijptjik/9408623/raw/b237fa5848349a14a14e5d4107dc7897c21951f5/wine.csv')
df.to_numpy()

X  = df.iloc[:,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]]
X.to_numpy()
y  = df.iloc[:,[0]]
y.to_numpy()
target_names = y

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
X_r = pca.fit(X).transform(X)

lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)

# Percentage of variance explained for each components
print('explained variance ratio (first two components): %s'
      % str(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))

plt.figure()
colors = ['navy', 'turquoise', 'darkorange']
lw = 2

for color, i, target_name in zip(colors, [0, 1, 2], target_names):
    plt.scatter(X_r[y == i, 0], X_r[y == i, 1], color=color, alpha=.8, lw=lw,
                label=target_name)
```

Comment: Since the error comes from a `matplotlib` command, it should be only natural to include the respective tag here instead of `pandas` and `numpy`. Plus, any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (since never executed) and should not be included here (edited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your `y` vs the `y` in the example script, you will see that your `y` has multiple dimensions even if the second dim is of length 0. You need to remove this 2nd dimension which can be done via `np.squeeze`

```
y = np.squeeze(df.loc[:,['Wine']].to_numpy())
```

Here is the full code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tijptjik/9408623/raw/b237fa5848349a14a14e5d4107dc7897c21951f5/wine.csv')

X = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Wine'].to_numpy()
y = np.squeeze(df.loc[:,['Wine']].to_numpy())
target_names = ['first', 'sceond', 'third']

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
X_r = pca.fit(X).transform(X)

lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)


lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)

# Percentage of variance explained for each components
print('explained variance ratio (first two components): %s'
    % str(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))

plt.figure()
colors = ['navy', 'turquoise', 'darkorange']
lw = 2

for color, i, target_name in zip(colors, [1,2,3], target_names):
    plt.scatter(X_r[y == i, 0], X_r[y == i, 1], color=color, alpha=.8, lw=lw,
                label=target_name)
plt.legend(loc='best', shadow=False, scatterpoints=1)
plt.title('PCA of Wine dataset')

plt.figure()
for color, i, target_name in zip(colors, [1, 2, 3], target_names):
    plt.scatter(X_r2[y == i, 0], X_r2[y == i, 1], alpha=.8, color=color,
                label=target_name)
plt.legend(loc='best', shadow=False, scatterpoints=1)
plt.title('LDA of Wine dataset')

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any reason why the "first" points are not in the LDA plot?